# Solving Ordinary Differential Equation with exact form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have found this problem of ODE in my textbook but i can't find any way to solve it $$x^2(y+1)dx+y^2(x-1)dy  = 0$$
I tried to solve it using reducible exact equation rules but i couldn't solve it. Please help me out.

Comment: You couldn't solve it using exact equation rules because your ODE isn't exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy because it is a seperable equation:
$$
x^2(y+1)dx = y^2(1-x)dy \\
\frac{x^2}{1-x}dx = \frac{y^2}{1+y}dy \\
\int \frac{x^2}{1-x}dx = \int \frac{y^2}{1+y}dy \\
\frac12(x-1)(x+3)-\log(1-x) +C = \frac12(y+1)(y-3) + \log(1+y)
$$
and you can simplify that however you wish.